# Script stopped working all of a sudden - copying stuff from one sheet to the other

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, ive been running this script for the past 3 months with no issues. Its simply supposed to iterate thru a spreadsheet and check whether certain rows have the necessary conditions to be copied over to another sheet. If so, copy that so the other sheet and delete that row in the original one.

```
function copyIfConditions() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName("NUEVOS INGRESOS Y EXPEDIENTES EN TRAMITE");//Changed sheet name
  const ash = ss.getSheetByName("CASOS ARCHIVADOS/FINALIZADOS");
  const spA = ["Finalizado_Archivado", "Remitida_a_otro_juzgado_conexidad", "Remitida_UACF", "Remitida_a_otro_juzgado_por_recusacion", "Remitida_a_otro_Juzgado_por_cuestion_de_turno", "Remitida_a_otros_fueros"];
  if (ssh.getLastRow() == 1) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('No data!', 'End of script ️');
    return;
  }
  const vs = ssh.getRange(2, 1, ssh.getLastRow() - 1, ssh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const archiveData = [];
  let d = 0;//delete counter
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (~spA.indexOf(r[35])) {
      archiveData.push(r);
      ssh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);
    }
  });
  ash.getRange(ash.getLastRow() + 1, 1, archiveData.length, archiveData[0].length).setValues(archiveData);
}
```

now, while trying to execute it, it throws out this error, which never happened before?
idk, ive no clue why its not working now and id like to fix it. yeah.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
@ CopyIfArchived.gs:19
```

Comment: Is it possible that `NUEVOS INGRESOS Y EXPEDIENTES EN TRAMITE` is empty? and `ssh.getRange(2, 1, ssh.getLastRow() - 1, ssh.getLastColumn()).getValues();` is retrieving an empty array? And because that, when trying to access `archiveData` the script detects it as empty

Comment: wait i tried to do     ```if (~spA.indexOf(r[34])) {``` instead and it seems to work now, oopsie

Comment: Can you explain why are you using the [`~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) operator?

Answer (score 0):

Your receiving this error when there is no data pushed to `archiveData`. Meaning, `archiveData[0]` does not exist (undefined).

Before setting your values, try:

```
if (archiveData.length) {
  ash.getRange(ash.getLastRow() + 1, 1, archiveData.length, archiveData[0].length).setValues(archiveData);
}
```

Comment: i dont get any errors this way, but it still doesnt work like it used to, which is the weird this, it just used to WORK.

Comment: Now that we've solved that issue, what specifically isn't working?

Comment: it turned out to be a silly mistake on my part! my bad